# Lookup Tables vs entry into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lookup

I have a question, in a T-SQL setting which is faster and better and futureproof?

Is it easier to have a lookup table with IDs and status entries as so

```
ID | Status
-------------
01 | Success
02 | Failure
03 | Processing
```

Or is it better to just enter the status values in per row?

How does this effect writing queries, is it good relational database design to use a lookup table rather than just entering a status into rows? Is one faster than the other?

I feel that lookup tables are the way to go, but I'm not seeing that so much in some databases.

Comment: I'd also like to note, in some situations, these status will never be used in another table that I know of and I'm not sure how often they'll change.

Comment: In that case just put a new column in your table.

Comment: Is the status "Failure" going to change in that it is named something else, or that it means something else?

Comment: In this case I used this as an example, but it is possible that Failure could result in meaning something else, or that there could be potentially new types of failure status added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use a separate status table for those items.  Then you will use a foreign key between your main table and the separate status table.  As far as querying you will just use a `JOIN` to include the actual status name.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t
LEFT JOIN yourStatus s
    t.sid = s.id
```

I think it allows for more flexibility, in the event your status names change you are only changing the values in your separate table rather than performing an `UPDATE` against your main table.

Your table structure could be similar to this:

```
MainTable
id int PK,
sid int FK - to status table
col3,
col4...

Status Table
id int PK - 
name varchar(50)
IsActive bit
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a better way to do that. It depends in your business logic and the amount of data that you are storing.

Typically is recommended to use a lockup table because you avoid duplicate data and if you wish to load just the status values (without repitition) it'll be more fast. Imagine that you want to create a drop down with the status value. You just have to make a

```
select * from lockup_table.
```

Then you want to select the rows with the status **Processing**

```
SELECT *FROM table t
LEFT JOIN lockup_table lt ON t.sid = lt.id 
WHERE lt.status LIKE 'Processing'
```

It'll remains fast too because your SGBD will use the power of pk indexes.

But sometimes it was better to have duplicate data, avoiding join operations. If you noitece that the joins operations is taking a while you should try to remove the lockup table and see if your performance was improved with that changes. You can create a index to for that column too. It'll improve the performance.

**In conclusion**, if you want a status column with a static values (Success, Processing, Failure) you don't need a lockup table. But if you want a unlimited range of values with dynamic values so you can be able to add more status values tomorrow, etc., you should create a lockup table.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is always better to have ID's and use that as foreign keys in your tables. I think it is the most future proof solution. For this situation specially if you want to filter by status, it can speed thinks up because it will not compare strings.

Also you can use this status tables for other tables in your database and it is easier to cross data.

And it is easier to index.

So in my opinion, I think that's the way to go.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Checklist to NOT qualify using the Lookup Table

1. Will the users want to modify this list?
2. Is this list more than 10 items?
3. Do you expect this list to expand in the future?
4. Does it have more than two columns that depend on the ID/CODE/PK?

If the answer to any of this is 'Yes' create a table and use the PK as an FK in your Primary table. This is the only thing you should be doing!

Otherwise, if the list is finite and represents minimal status codes go for an enum type.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I use status tables, but the primary key isn't an int but rather a varchar(6). This makes it easy to run ad-hoc reports, while ensuring that the status field is not free-form.

My status tables generally have the following fields:

```
create table foo_status (
    status      varchar(6) primary key,
    active      bit,
    name        nvarchar(255),
    description ntext null
);
```

and the data table references it through a foreign key

```
create table foo (
    ...
    status varchar(6) foreign key references foo_status(status)
    ...
);
create clustered index foo_fk_status_index on foo(status);
```

Comment: Why does a primary key as varchar make ad-hoc reports easier to run?

Comment: Why is an abbreviation of a status better encoding than a tinyint? I'm not sure how this makes anything better, especially if the name changes later - now the abbreviation doesn't make sense.

Comment: because I can say `select ... where status = 'error'` (and even `where status like 'err%'`), instead of `where status = 123`.

Comment: But that's not a very good thing, wildcards degrade performance.

Comment: @j0N45 how else would you select all rows with statuses that have names starting with `err`?  ..seems to me you'll have to use a wildcard somewhere..?

Comment: @AnandPhadke using a status table, or making the primary key of the status table a mnemonic rather than an integer?

Comment: For this scenario I guess PK would be integer and description would be varchar and name also varchar

Comment: @AnandPhadke sorry for being unclear, I was asking why you thought the design was bad for future changes?  Was it because you think a status table is bad, or because you think a primary key that is a mnemonic (and not an integer) is bad?  (and why do you think it's bad :-)

Comment: As this table data increases and when you join this table with other tables,it will affect on performance.Also due to non integer Pk,it has to convert it to int and compare with other ids as most of the cases PK's will be integer fields.And also I dont think we need any description for the status flags.

Comment: @AnandPhadke there is not conversion to int (I've updated my answer with the data table and the fk index to demonstrate).

Comment: @thebjorn You use it but not in the main table, if you have some several million records, its better if you just have some index in the foreign key and join the two tables, applying the wildcard in the status table. I think it will generate a better execution plan, but the better is to test it.

Comment: @j0N45 you should always index your foreign keys -- and since you already have a clustered index on the status column... `like`-queries should be fast, right? :-)

Comment: @thebjorn But... =) if you create a clustered index on the status solumn, then inserts, deletes and updates will have a big impact on performance, you will speed up report generation but you degrade operational performance.

Comment: @j0N45 the most common action on a status column is to select all rows that have a given status. You'll need an index on the status column to do that in any reasonable fashion (that the column is a foreign key tells you that you need to create an index..)

Comment: @thebjorn I agree, but in the case of the status column is in the main table (which was the discussion) then you should create a non-clustered index not a clustered one, because you don't want to re-index your main table due to changes in the status column. Actually the way you have it in the example, I would prefer to create a non-clustered.